# Unexplainable bug in my code

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

So I'm trying to write a small application that changes a line in registry to enable a certain thing..

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD transparenton = 0x00000001;
DWORD transparentoff = 0x00000000;

using namespace std;

void pause();
void act(PHKEY key);
void enableTransparency();
void disableTransparency();


int main()
{
    cout << "\tStart Menu Blurrier\n";
    cout << "Make your Windows 10 start menu background blurry like in Windows 7\nAutomatic On/Off\n";
    pause();
    PHKEY result;
    RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\\EnableBlurBehind", result);
    act(result);
    //enableTransparency();
    RegCloseKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
    pause();
}

void pause()
{
    cout << "Press [ENTER] to continue...";
    cin.get();
    system("cls");
}

void act(PHKEY key)
{
    DWORD l = (DWORD)key;
    if(l==transparenton){
        disableTransparency(); 
    }
    else{
        enableTransparency(); 
    }
}

void disableTransparency()
{
    RegSetKeyValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\\",
        "EnableBlurBehind",
        REG_DWORD, 
        &transparentoff,
        sizeof(transparentoff));
}

void enableTransparency()
{
    RegSetKeyValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\\",
        "EnableBlurBehind", 
        REG_DWORD, 
        &transparenton,
        sizeof(transparenton));
}
```

Ok, the bug is in the void act

```
void act(PHKEY key)
{
    DWORD l = (DWORD)key;
    if(l==transparenton){
        disableTransparency(); 
    }
    else{
        enableTransparency(); 
    }
}
```

It can detect when it's on and turn it off but it can't detect when it's off and turn it on.

1) The enableTransparency function works fine, because if I call it directly it works.
2) I've also tried two seperate if's (one for on and another for off) with no results! also tried equaling to NULL instead of transparentoff or using an else..
Nothing works.

What the hell are these c++-only bugs I seem to have every now and then.

Comment: Why do you think casting `PHKEY` to DWORD and comparing it with a constant is meaningful? And why are you passing an uninitialized pointer to `RegOpenKeyA`?

Comment: Passing an unitialized pointer was the only way to go since it required an LPCVOID which is a pointer to something? Correct me if I'm wrong... If then how should I go about doing it?

Comment: I guess you need a local variable of type `HKEY` and the you pass a pointer to it to `RegOpenKeyA`. That'll give you the handle. But of course comparing a handle to a constant is still meaningless.

Comment: @CodesInChaos well, that didn't work or maybe I'm not doing it correctly.. HKEY is not accepted in RegOpenKeyA , if you mean't PHKEY I can't make it a pointer and call it with a pointer either, doesn't work

Comment: Instead of simply wondering why it doesn't work, you need to use the debugger to step through the code and determine what the actual value of the "key" parameter is.

Comment: I've done that in the beggining and it correctly shows either 0000001 or 000000 (whatever it's written there)

Comment: But Okay I'll do that again

Comment: @MW2TopTenWORLD When an API function requires a pointer, it does not mean that you declare a pointer and pass it to the function.  The function wants the *address* of an existing `HKEY`.  A function can do nothing with the pointer you pass to it except to check for NULL, or worse, try to dereference it, and cause all sorts of problems.  `HKEY result;
    RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\\EnableBlurBehind", &result);` -- See that `&` character?

Comment: Okay yeah , there's a problem with it ( https://gyazo.com/9f7d0846f6d9621fab0d2fc8a7294fe2 ) .. (it's for enableblurbehind) I'll try to figurei it out, if anyone knows something give suggestions

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would have sworn I tried that and it didn't work.. I must have tried it with PHKEY.. thanks will see if any more problems occur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code (using legacy APIs, using bad parameters, missing logic, etc).

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

const DWORD transparenton = 0x00000001;
const DWORD transparentoff = 0x00000000;

using namespace std;

void pause();
void act(HKEY key);
bool getTransparency(HKEY key, DWORD &value);
void setTransparency(HKEY key, DWORD value);

int main()
{
    cout << "\tStart Menu Blurrier\n";
    cout << "Make your Windows 10 start menu background blurry like in Windows 7\nAutomatic On/Off\n";
    pause();

    HKEY hKey;
    LONG result = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        act(hKey);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return 0;
}

void pause()
{
    cout << "Press [ENTER] to continue...";
    cin.get();
    system("cls");
}

void act(HKEY key)
{
    DWORD value;
    if (getTransparency(key, value))
    {
        if (value == transparenton) {
            setTransparency(key, transparentoff);
        }
        else {
            setTransparency(key, transparenton);
        }
    }
}

bool getTransparency(HKEY key, DWORD &value)
{
    DWORD size = sizeof(value);
    LONG result = RegQueryValueExW(key, L"EnableBlurBehind", NULL, NULL, (BYTE*)&value, &size);
    if (result == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        value = transparentoff;
        result = 0;
    }
    return (result == 0);
}

void setTransparency(HKEY key, DWORD value)
{
    RegSetValueExW(key, L"EnableBlurBehind", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I won't just copy the code I will actually study it and learn it :)

Comment: @MW2TopTenWORLD: The way to say *"Thank you!"* on stackoverflow is by voting on answers (and questions), once you have enough reputation. You can get some initial reputation for free. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for information.